# error while installing Cilk Plus compiler on macOS Catalina and Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, macos, cilk-plus, cilk

I'm trying to instal Cilk Plus compiler, on a iMac with macOS Catalina and Xcode 11 with this [guidelines](https://cilkplus.github.io),

I used the command

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DINTEL_SPECIFIC_CILKPLUS=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/install/prefix -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ ..
```

to create the binaries, and when I try to instal with the command

```
make && make install
```

show me the error

```
/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:144:22: error: conflicting types for 'dispatch_sync' DISPATCH_INTERCEPT_B(dispatch_sync)
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/queue.h:288:1: note: previous declaration is here dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_t queue, DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block);

/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:145:22: error: conflicting types for 'dispatch_barrier_sync' DISPATCH_INTERCEPT_B(dispatch_barrier_sync)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/queue.h:1363:1: note: previous declaration is here dispatch_barrier_sync(dispatch_queue_t queue,

/cilk/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc:162:24: error: conflicting types for 'dispatch_once' TSAN_INTERCEPTOR(void, dispatch_once, dispatch_once_t *predicate,

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/once.h:73:1: note: previous declaration is here 

dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,

3 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/rtl/tsan_libdispatch_mac.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so my question is, Cilk plus is compatible with macOS Catalina and Xcode 11? if it is how I can solve this errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Cilk Plus was [deprecated](https://www.cilkplus.org) in 2018, so there is little chance that it works on the latest platform.